# Django AttributeError in settings.py file

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, virtualenv, python-module

I've been stuck all day on what seems to be a very silly import problem.  From my Django project directory, I can import a module and run a function just fime:

```
(msg-gw)slashingweapon:~/msg-gw/www$ python 
>>> import snpp
>>> snpp.config_url('snpp://server.name.com:1234?user=me&pass=whatever')
{'host': 'server.name.com', 'pass': 'whatever', 'port': 1234, 'user': 'me'}
```

But when I try to run my app, either through `manage.py` or by `gunicorn`, I get an attribute error:

```
(msg-gw)slashingweapon:~/msg-gw/www$ python manage.py runserver 8000
  File "/home/slashingweapon/msg-gw/www/project/settings.py", line 26, in <module>
    SNPP = snpp.config_url('snpp://server.name.com:1234?user=me&pass=whatever')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'config_url'
```

The two relevant lines in my `settings.py` file are exactly what you would expect.  Notice that I can import the module just fine, but the `config_url()` function isn't found.

```
import snpp
SNPP = snpp.config_url('snpp://server.name.com:1234?user=me&pass=whatever')
```

The directory layout is exactly what you would expect:

```
www
  |
  +-project
  |   +-__init__.py
  |   +-settings.py
  |   +-urls.py
  |   +-views.py
  |   +-wsgi.py
  |
  +-snpp
      +-__init__.py
      +-protocol.py
      +-views.py
      +-urls.py
```

The `config_url()` function is defined inside `snpp/__init__.py`

I have tried all kinds of things:

- `from snpp import config_url`
- move `config_url` to the file `snpp/config` and then import with

  - `import snpp.confg`
  - `from snpp.config import config_url`
  - `from snpp import config` and then invoke through `config.config_url()`

The `__init__.py` file is nothing special.  It just lets you encode some server information as a string, so you can stick your SNPP config into the environment:

```
import urlparse

def config_url(urlStr):

    config = {
        'host':None,
        'port':444,
        'user':None,
        'pass':None,
    }

    url = urlparse.urlparse(urlStr)
    if url.scheme == 'snpp':
        locParts = url.netloc.split(":")
        config['host'] = locParts[0]
        if len(locParts) > 1:
            port = int(locParts[1])
            if port > 0:
                config['port'] = port

        args = urlparse.parse_qs(url.query)
        config['user'] = args.get('user', [None])[0]
        config['pass'] = args.get('pass', [None])[0]

    return config
```

I am using Python 2.7, django 1.5.1, and virtualenv.

Other parts of my project work well.  When I print out the path in my browser, it looks correct.  Importing `snpp` should not be a problem, since `snpp` is in the `www` directory:

- /home/slashingweapon/msg-gw/www
- /home/slashingweapon/msg-gw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
- /home/slashingweapon/msg-gw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
- /home/slashingweapon/msg-gw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_json_rpc-0.6.2-py2.7.egg
- /home/slashingweapon/msg-gw/lib/python27.zip
- /home/slashingweapon/msg-gw/lib/python2.7
- ... etc ...

It doesn't matter if the snpp module is in my `INSTALLED_APPS` list or not.  I get the same result.

**Solved**

With the help of SO denizens, I found the problem.

I had refactored my application by moving some reusable code pieces from the `project` directory to the new `snpp` directory.  When I did that, I neglected to move or delete the `*.pyc` files.

The value of `snpp.__file__` was:

```
/home/slashingweapon/msg-gw/www/project/snpp.pyc
```

instead of the expected:

```
/home/slashingweapon/msg-gw/www/snpp/__init__.pyc
```

During the import process, Python was looking in `project/` before `snpp/` and finding an old `snpp.pyc` file.  It would import the old pyc file and be satisfied, thus ignoring the entire `snpp/` dir.

Had I been a little sharper (or a little more experienced with Python) I might have noticed that I was getting some strange import behavior in general whenever I tried to import anything from `snpp/`.  It should have occurred to me that the whole module was wonky, and not just the one function I was trying to use at the moment.

Comment: you might need to append `../snpp` to your `sys.path`. Try printing `sys.path` and see if the root directory of your project is listed.

Comment: It finds the snpp directory just fine.  I know because if I change the import statement to `import snppx` I get an ImportError exception on that line of code.  I have edited the post a little to clarify my path.

Comment: Huh.  I'm grasping at straws here, but have you tried commenting out the settings.py bit, running manage.py shell and checking the snpp path and presence of the config_url name in that Python environment?  If it's somehow getting something other than your module in the import, that could explain this.

Comment: you could check what exactly is being imported using snpp.__file__ after import snpp statement.

Comment: Wow, that was it.  @Omie, if you repost your comment as an answer I'll accept it.  Explanation is forthcoming in my next edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what exactly is being imported by using

```
snpp.__file__
```

right after `import snpp` statement.

Actually import might not be from the path you are expecting to see.